# how to create space between anchor tag elements in loop in paging

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a paging option in my website. The problem is that the paging digits is not align in the appropriate way in fact the images is attached. [This is my image in which number not align correctly

This is output of my paging numbers:

[image: This is output of my paging numbers]

This is my code.

```
    <section>
              <div class="container" style="padding-bottom:10px; font-size:20px;">
                            <?php $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM videos ";
                            $query = $conn->query($sql1);
                            // Return the number of rows in result set
                            $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
                            $a=$rowcount/3;
                            $a= ceil($a);
                               for($b=1; $b<=$a; $b++)
                                  {
                                  ?> <a style=" " href="index.php?page=<?php echo $b; ?>"><?php echo $b. "      " ?> </a> <?php
                                  }?>
               </div>
     </section>
```

But I want to align these numbering in this way:

This image exactly shows requirement of my result:

[image: This image exactly shows requirement of my result]

please anyone can help me. how to fix it. thanks

Comment: check out my answer :)

Comment: ok bro. i'll check

Comment: check again, i edited a little bit, there was a problem with escaping

Comment: it was working fine bro. but a little bit problem. the how to create space vertically between numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a `table` as grid

Try this

```
<table>
<tr>
 <?php 
    $numbers_per_row = 5;
    $rowi= 0; 
    $numbers_limit = 25;
    for($b=1; $b<=$numbers_limit ; $b++)
        {
    echo '<td><a href="index.php?page='.$b.'">'.$b.'</td>';
      if($rowi<=$numbers_per_row) {
          $rowi++;
         } 
      else { echo  '</tr><tr style="margin-top:10px;">'; 
                               /* <-- change it ^ to what you want */
      /* Reset counter */ 
      $rowi = 0; }

     }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: It was working fine bro. But a little bit problem. How to create space vertically between numbers? As between 1 and 6 vertically.